# How to increase quota youtube api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

So im trying to upload shorts on my youtube channels every day but the quota gets exceeded really quickly (after 6 video's).

Is there any way I can increase my queries to 50.000?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it's not related to programming.

Comment: You need to fill a Google form to request a quota increase (cf https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits).

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API website says that 1600 quota units are required to upload a single video to the YouTube website through the videos.insert method of the YouTube API. Thus, for instance, if you are expecting users to upload 100 videos to your YouTube channel in a single day, your Google Cloud project should have a quota of at least 1600 * 100 = 160,000 units.

The quota limits reset every 24 hours. New Google Cloud projects have lower quota and you’ll have to request YouTube to increase your quota if you are expecting a higher number of videos.

Follow this [doc Link](https://www.labnol.org/youtube-quota-request-201016#request-youtube-to-increase-quota) How to Request an Additional Quota for your YouTube API Project.  This is the [Request Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en) needed to submit to Youtube.